# code is getting executed even after res.send

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, joi

so, I'm working on a full stack mern app and but in the authentication page, the code is getting executed even after `res.send`

```
import User from "../models/user.js";
import { registerValidation } from "../validation.js";
const router = Router();
//!Hapijoi

//!
router.get("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = registerValidation(req.body);
  if (error) res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

  const email = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
  if (email) return res.status(400).send("email exists");
  const user = new User(req.body);
  try {
    const saveduser = await user.save();
    res.send(saveduser);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
export default router;
```

so, even after the line `if (error) res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);` and `if (email) return res.status(400).send("email exists");` the data is stored in the db
but i saw that the code wont be executed after `res.send`
what should i do pls help

Comment: `res.send()` is JUST a regular function call.  Your function body keeps on executing successive lines of code just like it does after any other function call.  If you want the function to exit, add a `return;` statement after the `res.send()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to `return` in order to prevent further code execution which could lead to unwanted behaviors, and errors saying that the response has already been sent. So just write this:

```
if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
```

Just like you did here:

```
if (email) return res.status(400).send("email exists");
```

Note that the return value of an Express callback is being ignored, so you could write anything after the `return`, its purpose is just to stop the function execution.